# How to get the content between two self-defined tags?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a simple template system, and I have a problem.  If I have a string like this:

```
{% for x in xx %}
    some string 1
{% endfor %}

{% for y in yy %}
    some string 2
{% endfor %}
```

How could I get the contents `some string 1` and `some string 2`. I try to match them with the regular expression, which looks for `{% for .+ in .+ %}` and `{% endfor %}` and get the contents between them, but in this case, what it got is:

```
    some string 1
{% endfor %}

{% for y in yy %}
    some string 2
```

What should I do?

**UPDATE:**
I think what I need is a regular expression which can do things like this:

```
count = 0
while not the end:
    if match("{% for .+ in .+ %}")
        count += 1
    else if match("{% endfor %}")
        count -= 1
    if count == 0 
        // get contents between the first {% for in %} and the last {% endfor %}
```

Can regular expression count?

Comment: What is the significant difference between `{% for x in xx %}` and `<? foreach( $xx as $x ): ?>`? I strongly advice against creating your own flavor of template language, unless it's for learning purposes. As Stephan stated, PHP makes for an excellent template language already. And the extra layer will only create more complexity and CPU cycles, with little added value.

Comment: @fireeyedboy yes, it has some learning purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP already makes an excellent templating system, why do you want to complicate it further by relying on what will become a VERY complicated RegEx if you want a decent templating system.

Comment: I just want a simple template system which support loops

Comment: PHP does this already though, so what advantages do you get from adding another layer of complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you're using `.*` somewhere in your regex, which is greedy. Try using `.*?` instead, which is non-greedy.

(Also, for any kind of tag nesting, you aren't going to want to use regex like that; instead you'll need to actually have some kind of stack involved.)

Comment: Yes, I will write a recursive function to support nested loops